# WordPress - WYSIWYG bug on post edit

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, tinymce, wysiwyg

Im running Wordpress 4.8.2 and having an issue with the WYSIWYG editor.

When editing a blog post, the text in the body of the post briefly flashes in the WYSIWYG editor (tinymce )as the page loads, but when the page completes loading, the text disappears from the editor.

It looks like the text is supposed to be `iframe`'d in but there is no content in the iframe.

Is anyone aware of this bug or have an idea what the issue could be?

Comment: First step in debugging Wordpress is disable everything... Plugins, themes, etc.  Use the basic 2017 theme with no plugins enabled, and see if it's still happening.  If not, start turning things back on until it starts again.  Eventually you'll find it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a current known issue so the fix is to add the following to your wp-config.php file

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```